# how to split the result in array React/Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

I will explain my problem to you today: the following code works fine, I get my database, then I use a map function, so everything is fine. My question and the next, I get a table in it I have an object that contains an array. This table has the following form:

```
 [{"title":"Lagunitas IPA (Demi-Pinte","quantity":2}]
```

and it is possible to recover one of the two pieces of data because when I map over the array I get all of it.

Do you have an idea of how to fix this?

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { CardText,  Col } from 'reactstrap';
    import axios from 'axios'

    const entrypoint = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT+'/api';

    class AdminPage  extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],   
              },
        };
    }

    getRandom = async () => {

        const res = await axios.get(
            entrypoint + "/alluserpls"
        )
        this.setState({ data: res.data })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getRandom()
    }
    render() {

        let datas = this.state.data.map(datass => {
          return (
              <div >
                  <Col sm="12" key={datass.id}">
                          <CardText> Commande{datass.items}</CardText>
                  </Col>
              </div>
          )
      })
        return (
        <div> 
        {datas}
      </div>
        )
     }
   }

export default AdminPage
```

Comment: try debuging and seeing what exactly is in datass.items and datass.id. you may need to access datass.items[0] and datass.items[1] however this is only an educated guess

Comment: {datass.title} will show title of each

Comment: inside <CardText> Commande{datass.title}</CardText> like this I mean

Comment: @bwright  {
        "id": 118,
        "title": "brand",
        "items": "[{\"title\":\"Lagunitas IPA (Demi-Pinte\",\"quantity\":2}]"
    }

Comment: @PramodNikam i cant  <CardText> Commande{datass.title}</CardText> because on my table i have " title"

Answer (score 1):

when you want to get a data from server , it is in json format so it can transfer from server to client. so when you receive on the client side , make sure to parse it, this will give you the data back into an object form that u can use each property of your data in mapping them.

lets assume you are receiving this data

```
 [{"title":"Lagunitas IPA (Demi-Pinte","quantity":2}]
```

this data in json format ,now you need to parse it to be able to use the properties seperately

in your getRandom method

```
getRandom = async () => {

   const res = await axios.get(
      entrypoint + "/alluserpls"
   )
   let parsedData = JSON.parse(res.data);
   this.setState({ data: parsedData  })
}
```

now you have the data stored as an array of objects, in render you can map it and use it as

```
let datas = this.state.data.map((datass,index) => {
    return (
       <div>
           <Col sm="12" key={index}">
               <Col sm="6">
               Title : {datass.title}
               </Col>
               <Col sm="6">
               Quantity: {datass.quantity}
               </Col>
           </Col>
       </div>
    )
 })
```

this will show the value of quantity and title separately.

Comment: i got error  AdminPage.js:83 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: you need to consider if the data you are getting in the res is json or not first.. the data u posted above is accurate.

Comment: Hi ,
the problem i think and that i have both format in the same table. 
What do you think ?my table looks like this to be precise {
        "id": 118,
        "name": "",
        "phone": "1643416502",
        "randomID": "456",
        "title": "",
        "quantity": "",
        "items": "[{\"title\":\"Lagunitas IPA (Demi-Pinte\",\"quantity\":2}]"
    }

Comment: and I really want to recover Items in two parts

Comment: { "id": 118, "name": "", "phone": "1643416502", "randomID": "456", "title": "", "quantity": "", "items": "[{\"title\":\"Lagunitas IPA (Demi-Pinte\",\"quantity\":2}]" }

is also in json , you should be able to parse it, u can check in the console if it is the exact data you receive in res.data

Comment: like this ?                                                                            
        console.log(this.state.data)                                                       
        let datas = this.state.data.map((datass,index) => {
        return                                                                                                                       
if that's so , I think I receive an empty board , result on myconsoleLog length: 0 , __proto__:Array(0)

Comment: in getRandom function before setting the state for res.data , console.log(res.data) to check what you receive from the server itselfr

Comment: getRandom = async () => {

    const res = await axios.get(
       entrypoint + "/alluserpls"
    )
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(res.data);
    console.log(res.data)
    this.setState({ data: parsedData  })
 } like this ? if correct nothing and same error

Answer (score 0):

```
    getRandom = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get(
                entrypoint + "/alluserpls"
            )
            const data = res.json();
            this.setState({ data })
        }
```

Comment: and for inside<CardText> Commande{}</CardText> what is the code if i want to take only "quantity " for " items" ?

Comment: let datas = this.state.data.map(datass => {
          return (
                  <Col sm="12" key={datass.id}">
                          <CardText> Commande{datass.quantity}</CardText>
                  </Col>
          )
      })

Comment: i have error ,  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.json is not a function
    at AdminPage.js:82
    at l (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:264)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:98)
    at r (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at u (asyncToGenerator.js:25)

Comment: quantity string or number?

Comment: this schema "items": "[{\"title\":\"Lagunitas IPA (Demi-Pinte\",\"quantity\":2}]" } so is string i guess

Comment: complet schema is that { "id": 118, "title": "brand", "items": "[{\"title\":\"Lagunitas IPA (Demi-Pinte\",\"quantity\":2}]" }

Comment: This wound up on the low-quality posts review queue to see if it should be deleted, because you need to edit it and add some text to explain how this solves the problem.  StackOverflow frowns upon code-only answers, because when people are reading through a lot of answers they don't want to have to reverse engineer everything to figure out what is intended when you could just explain it.